# Reading from file not reading stringstream

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to read from a text file of form:

```
mdasd tgfor,100,23
sfier sdfdor,2,3
mmmmmm,232,452
```

using this function: Which i test in every way i could think of but can't manage to amke it work:

```
void StudentRepository::loadStudents(){
    ifstream fl;
    fl.open("studs.txt");
    Student st("",0,0);
    string str,s;
    stringstream ss;
    int i;
    int loc;
    if(fl.is_open()){
        while(getline(fl,str)){
            cout<<"string: "<<str<<endl;

            loc = str.find(",");
            ss << str.substr(0,loc);
            s = ss.str();

            cout<<"name: "<<s<<endl;

            st.setName(s);
            ss.str("");
            str.erase(0,loc+1);

            loc = str.find(",");
            ss << str.substr(0,loc);
            ss >> i;

            cout<<"id:"<<i<<endl;

            st.setId(i);
            ss.str("");
            str.erase(0,loc);
            ss >> i;
            st.setGroup(i);
            ss.str("");

            cout<<"gr:"<<i<<endl;
            students.push_back(st);

            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"~~~ File couldn't be open! ~~~"<<endl;
    }
    fl.close();
}
```

But as i can show you inthe run it read only the first name from the first line than everything is blank:

```
string: mqqeeqw tuwqer,23,32 /// ID AND GROUP are initializate with 0 thats 
name: mqqeeqw tuwqer         /// why they have that values... why does it not work?
id:0
gr:0

string: maier tudor,2,3
name: 
id:0
gr:0

string: maier tudor,0,0
name: 
id:0
gr:0
```

Comment: Are you supposed to use a stringstream here? I don't see what good it does.

Comment: to convert fro mstring back to ints :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getline()` on a `std::stringstream` with a custom delimiter, something like this:

```
if(fl.is_open()){
    while(getline(fl,str)){
        stringstream ss(str);
        string name, id, gr;
        while(ss) {
            getline(ss, name, ',');  // "," as delimiter
            getline(ss, id, ',');
            getline(ss, gr, ',');
        }

        cout << "name: " << name <<endl;
        cout << "id:" << id << endl;
        cout << "gr:" << gr << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have to get `int`s from `std::string`s though

Comment: managed thank you...  i got lots of problems because of my handmade sub delimitators and so on but i works just fine now :) thank you again,